# Игра snake на JavaFx

Tags: разработка-игр, javafx

Доброго времени суток, как можно поменять направление змейки так чтобы он не шел в обратную сторону сразу <-->.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class CanvasEx extends Application {
    final int size=500, dot_size=10, up=1, right=2, down=3, left=4;
    int delay=50, length=3, dir=2, food_x, food_y;
    Canvas canvas;
    GraphicsContext gc;
    int x[]=new int[size*size];
    int y[]=new int[size*size];
    Thread game;
    boolean lost=false;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        canvas=new Canvas(size,size);
        gc=canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        canvas.setFocusTraversable(true);
        root.getChildren().add(canvas);
        startGame();
        canvas.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent e) {
                KeyCode key=e.getCode();
                if(key.equals(KeyCode.UP)) dir=up;
                if(key.equals(KeyCode.DOWN)) dir=down;
                if(key.equals(KeyCode.LEFT)) dir=left;
                if(key.equals(KeyCode.RIGHT)) dir=right;
            }

        });
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, size, size);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    private void draw(GraphicsContext gc){
        gc.clearRect(0, 0, size, size);
        if(!lost){
            gc.setFill(Paint.valueOf("green"));
            gc.fillOval(food_x, food_y, dot_size, dot_size);
            gc.setFill(Paint.valueOf("red"));
            gc.fillOval(x[0], y[0], dot_size, dot_size);
            gc.setFill(Paint.valueOf("orange"));
            for(int i=1; i<length; i++){
                gc.fillOval(x[i], y[i], dot_size, dot_size);}

        }else{
            gc.setFill(Paint.valueOf("black"));
            gc.fillText("Game Over", size/2-50, size/2-15);
            game.stop();
        }
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private void startGame() {
        length=3;
        for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
            x[i]=50-i*dot_size;
            y[i]=50;
        }
        locateFood();
        game=new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true){
                    if(!lost){
                        checkFood();
                        checkCollision();
                        move();
                    }
                    draw(gc);
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(delay);
                    } catch(Exception e){};
                }
            }




        });
        game.start();
    }

    private void locateFood() {
        food_x=(int)(Math.random()*((size/dot_size)-1))*dot_size;
        food_y=(int)(Math.random()*((size/dot_size)-1))*dot_size;
    }
    private void checkFood() {
        if(x[0]==food_x && y[0]==food_y){
            length++;
            locateFood();
        }
    }
    private void checkCollision() {
        if(x[0]>=size) lost=true;
        if(y[0]>=size) lost=true;
        if(x[0]<0) lost=true;
        if(y[0]<0) lost=true;
        for(int i=3; i<length; i++)
            if(x[0]==x[i] && y[0]==y[i]) lost=true;
    }
    private void move() {
        for(int i=length-1;i>0;i--){
            x[i]=x[i-1];
            y[i]=y[i-1];
        }
        if(dir==up)y[0]-=dot_size;
        if(dir==down)y[0]+=dot_size;
        if(dir==right)x[0]+=dot_size;
        if(dir==left)x[0]-=dot_size;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется тут решение в лоб:

```
if(key.equals(KeyCode.UP)) dir=up;
if(key.equals(KeyCode.DOWN)) dir=down;
if(key.equals(KeyCode.LEFT)) dir=left;
if(key.equals(KeyCode.RIGHT)) dir=right;
```

В этом участке кода просто добавляем проверки на `dir != down` (в случае, если `KeyCode.UP`) и так далее.

Comment: Вот блин, не додумался) спасибо

Comment: @Mr.Iron Отметь как верный ответ и поставь плюс (если помог)